# decorate specific methods of a class

Tags: python, decorator, static-methods

i read about decorators and i am trying to decorate all the methods of a class WITHOUT static methods.

right now i just use the decorator i wrote for the specific functions that are not static, so i wonder if there is a way to both decorate a lot of methods but avoid static ones

what i get with my decorator:

```
TypeError: unbound method test() must be called with ClassTest instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

my decorator:

```
def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "test"
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, decorating a class is pretty simple:

```
def class_decorator(cls):
    # modify cls
    return cls
```

In order to add/remove/modify functionality to a method, you could call `setattr` with a decorated version of a method (or a variable):

```
setattr(some_class, some_attribute, decorator(some_callable))
```

As to differentiating between different types of methods, there are a couple of attributes you'll be able to use
to determine whether a method is an instance/class/static method.

A full working example:

```
def _is_instance_method(var):
    if not hasattr(var, '__call__'): # It's not a callable
        return False
    if not hasattr(var, 'im_self'): # It's a callable, but it's not a bound method
        return False
    if getattr(var, 'im_self') is not None: # At this point, if it's a class method,
                                            # it will be bound to the class, while
                                            # the instance method is still unbound
                                            # return False if it's bound (i.e. a class method)
        return False
    return True # All that remains is a callable, that's boundable, but not yet -- an instance method!

def func_decorator(func):
    def func_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "Inside %s!" % (func.__name__,)
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return func_wrapper

def class_decorator(cls):
    for attr in cls.__dict__:
        var = getattr(cls, attr)
        if _is_instance_method(var): # Determine whether the attribute is an instance method
            setattr(cls, attr, func_decorator(var)) # Replace the function with a decorated one
    return cls # Return the class with its new decorated instance methods

@class_decorator
class B(object):

    @staticmethod
    def static_method():
        return "static method"

    @classmethod
    def cls_method(cls):
       return "cls method"

    def instance_method(self):
       return "instance method"

print B.static_method() 
print B.cls_method()
b = B()
print b.instance_method()
```